# Task.ContinueWith runs before the first task finishes executing

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

I have created 3 Tasks. Task3 depend on the result from Task1 and Task2.
While debugging the code it executes correctly but while running the application Task3 gets execute before Task1 and Task2 complete.

Sample code :

```
enter code here

public void LoadData()
    {
            // Set up tasks
            Task Task1 = GetTask1Data();
            Task Task2 = GetTask2Data();
            Task Task3 = GetTask3Data();

            new TaskFactory(TaskScheduler).StartNew(() =>
            {
            // Start first
                Task1.Start();
                new TaskFactory(TaskScheduler).ContinueWhenAll(
                    new[] {Task1 },
                    completedTasks =>
                    {
                        Task2.Start();
                        Task2.ContinueWith(r => Task3.Start());
                    });
             }
        }
    }

 private Task GetTask3Data()
    {
        return new Task(() =>
            {
                Task<ICollection<Object>> task = SubTask1();
                if (task == null)
                {
                    return;
                }
                task.ContinueWith(result =>
                    {
                            if (result != null)
Debug.WriteLine("Got correct data");
                    });
            });
    }

private Task<ICollection<Object>> SubTask1()
    {
            return new TaskFactory(TaskScheduler).StartNew(() =>
                {
                    if (<bool condition return by Task1> && <book condition return by Task2>)
                   {
                         //Return executed data
                    }
                    return null;
                });
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Note that I would *highly* discourage you from having methods returning unstarted tasks.  Instead just don't call the task-generating methods until you're ready to start the tasks.  That would be the more idiomatic approach.

Comment: Servy, you mean to say methods that are called on Task.Start() should not contain further new tasks in that

Comment: I'm saying that you should almost never use the `Task` constructor to create unstarted tasks and then call `Start` on them later, at least outside of very exceptional situations.  I can think of only a handful of times where I've ever done it.  Have `GetTask1Data`, `GetTask2Data` etc. use `StartNew` to return an *already started* task, and then have your method that composes them wait to call those methods until you're ready to start the tasks, rather than calling the methods right away and then waiting to start them.  What you're doing isn't *wrong*, per say, it's just very unusual.

Comment: As per my understanding, If we create a new Task inside any Task then that will be the child of parent Task. So it should execute olnly if parent Task start.

Comment: Parent and child tasks? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997417(v=vs.110).aspx You have to make sure that the TaskCreationOption is set correctly. The other thing I would do is to take a look at the bool conditions and try to use synchronization primitives instead of normal types.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you might be using some kind of global state to hold the results of `Task1` and `Task2`. Try to compose your tasks into a flow.

```
var task1Result = await GetTask1();
var task2Result = await GetTask2();
var task3Result = await GetTask3(task1Result, task2Result);
```

Comment: he is asking for the reasons not for solution

Comment: The whole point of using `await` is to avoid manually adding the continuations.  If you do use `await` it's as simple as calling `await GetTask1();await GetTask2();await GetTask3();` and you're done.  Alternatively, you can have each be a continuation of the other.  You should be using one or the other, not both.

Comment: Yes. I am using other varibles to hold the results of Task1 and Task2. But need to ckeck in Task3